# redirecting from asp.net page to silverlight page in one solution

Tags: asp.net, sql, silverlight

I got a ASP.Net application with silverlight application in one solution now when i redirect a ASP.net page to sliverlight page I got this error popup in references

> **An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:2172/Middleware.svc'. This could be due to
>   attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper
>   cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP
>   services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish
>   a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP
>   headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal
>   types in the web service proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception
>   for more details.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to put cross domain and client access policy file on the root of your web applicaition.

Refer the below link.

[Making a Service Available Across Domain Boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)